# Strange behavior of MultipleLocator() with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm having trouble with this piece of code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter

majorLocator   = MultipleLocator(0.1)
majorFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%2.1f')

fig = plt.figure()
axes = []

for i in range(4):
    axes.append(fig.add_subplot(2,2,i+1))

for ax in axes:
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)
    ax.set_ylim(0,1)

axes[-1].set_ylim(1,2) #If you comment this line all works fine.

plt.show()
```

In my screen a tick issue appears.

[image]

But if I comment the line `axes[-1].set_ylim(1,2)` all the ticks are properly displayed. Is this a bug? Or I am doing it wrong?

(matplotlib '1.3.0')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're sharing the same locator object between multiple y-axis objects.

It's not a bug, but it is a subtle issue that can cause a lot of confusion.  The documentation could probably be more clear about this, but locators are expected to belong to a single `axis`.

You actually can share the same `Formatter` instance, but it's probably better not to, unless you're aware of the ramifications (changes to one will affect all).

Instead of recycling the same `Locator` and `Formatter` instances, create new ones for each axis:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.yaxis.set(major_locator=MultipleLocator(0.1),
                 major_formatter=FormatStrFormatter('%2.1f'))
    ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

axes[-1, -1].set_ylim(1, 2)

plt.show()
```

[image]