# python/matplotlib : imposed ticks with ticker partially missing

Tags: python, matplotlib, ticker

When plotting my figure with `plt.axis('auto')`, 'natural' x-ticks are written with frequency 500,

[image]

Wishing a frequency 200, I have used:

```
    import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

    ticks_loc = ticker.MultipleLocator(base=200)

    fig = plt.figure('Cutlines x-axis')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ...
    plt.axis('equal')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticks_loc)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticks_loc)
    plt.grid()
```

which gives,

[image]

Curiously

1. all the ticks are not represented (ticks -1000, -800, -600 are missing)
2. `plt.show()` differs from `savefig` (in `plt.show()` 'only' ticks -1000 and -800 are missing, not -600).

I have tried reducing the font size (with very tiny one) and/or by writing vertically -> no effect : always the same ticks are missing.

Is there a way to have all the ticks visible (in horizontal mode) ?

Comment: I don't reproduce this with your code above using plotting `x=np.linspace(-1000,1000,1000)` then `ax.plot(x,np.sin(np.pi*x/2000.))` with matplotlib version 1.4.3. I wonder if it is a bug with setting the same `ticks_loc` for y where the data range stops before 400... Also, try adding `bbox_inches='tight'` to savefig to address point 2.

Comment: Hi Ed : I am using version 1.5.1 for Matplotlib. Trying without y-axis ticks_loc I have the same results (ticks missing). Maybe a bug. To fix my problem, I use the julien's proposal given above. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange behavior of MultipleLocator() with subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743410/strange-behavior-of-multiplelocator-with-subplots)

Comment: Hi @user202729 , it was a long time ago, but the explanations (and the fixing) given in your related link seem to be relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you simply use `xticks` instead of `ticker`

```
fig = plt.figure('Cutlines x-axis')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
...
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
plt.xticks(np.arange(xlim[0], xlim[1]+200, 200))
```

Comment: Hello Julien : You 're right, that's the good way. I believe we could'nt get xlim corresponding to auto-rescaling. But it works perfectly .. and easily !