Why grid is not shown in this matplotlib script?
Using Python 3.12 and Matplotlib 3.8.4 on Ubuntu 22.04. I would like to see a uniform grid with 0.25 spacing. This snippet:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

gridSpacing = MultipleLocator(0.25)
plt.clf()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(gridSpacing)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_locator(gridSpacing)
plt.gca().grid(which='minor', axis='both')
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], color='r', linewidth=1, marker='o')
plt.show()

produces a plot with random grid when the window is small:

or no grid at all, when it is larger:

How to get a uniform grid with 0.25 spacing?
Note that I intend to use this snippet in a loop, that's why you see plt.clf(), etc.

I applied an answer from @Fatima and it works, but when the window is small, some grid lines are missing. It gets worse when I use set_major_locator, e.g.:
gridSpacing = MultipleLocator(0.25)
plt.clf()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(gridSpacing)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(gridSpacing)
plt.gca().grid()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], color='r', linewidth=1, marker='o')
plt.show()

which plots this:

Grid lines are missing regardless of window size. What is the reason?

Regarding your edit: You can't reuse a locator on the x and y axes. Create a second version of your gridSpacing (with a different name) to use on the y-axis. What's happening is when you use it on the y-axis, it's changing the location of the ticks (nothing below 0.75), so those are also being remove from the x-axis.

See here for a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743410/strange-behavior-of-multiplelocator-with-subplots

Also see the note at the bottom of the "tick locating" section here

@tmdavison Thank you. This was the source of my problem. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it as the best solution.
